# how to sort part of a dgv column

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataGridView with 10 columns full of unlocked data. Some columns are string data and some are TimeSpan time data. I want to sort on column 9 (a TimeSpan data column) in ascending order the first x number of rows and disregard the sorting of the remainder of rows. I have not seen any posts on this task and I am not sure it is possible. Is there a method in VB.NET that performs this task? I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: What does *unlocked data* mean? What is the DataSource of your DGV?

Comment: Probably the best approach might be to add an field to the data source for your DVG, then you can implement any custom sort algorithm you like

Comment: unlocked means the data is input from the keyboard or a CSV file. Data is not from a database.

Comment: I do not understand adding a field to the data source. The data source is the keyboard or a CSV file.

Comment: My bad I should have said unbound not unlocked

Comment: The TimeSpan values, e.g., 14:23:12 are converted to strings in order to be displayed in the DataGridView. What I wish for is a function ...  dgv2.Sort(dgv2.Columns(9 (rows o thru x)),System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending). but the "rows 0 thru x" doesn't exist.

Comment: You don't need to convert to string the TimeSpan, you need to set the ValueType of the Column to TimeSpan and provide a Format string, so your values are formatted as required and the underlying value is still a TimeSpan that sorts as a TimeSpan.

Comment: I am not having any problem with formatting, however thank you Jimi for your response. My problem is sorting column 9 rows 0 thru x and ignoring the remainder of the rows that follow.